# Known .aff problems?

Tags: aaf, omf, pro-tools, avid

I'm working on a new project.  The video editors have the latest avid version, and our sound team is working with the latest version of protools.  We've been encountering problems with that file extension, as opposed to an OMF.  Is this a known problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What sort of problem? I've never encountered any problems that weren't user generated I'm afraid to say (please don't take that wrong way).

Answer (score 2):

With the latest version of AVID, they've nicked the "Open Timeline" idea from FCP - you can pretty much put anything into the timeline and it will do it's best to work with it. Whether or not you like/agree/whatever, the feature is probably here to stay.

So, to answer your question, there are a number of issues with AAF, regarding Multiple sample rates in the timeline, multiple framerates in the timeline and some types of MXF media. The Avid/Digi forums have some info if you want to go searching, but MOST of the errors are due to the first two. The solution seems to be to use embedded media and force it to WAV format in the export box. (I'm pretty sure you can do this with consolidated media as well, but I've never tried it.)

Comment: Add one more to the list. If you are having persistent issues (esp. Assertion Errors) on your AAF, have the editor open the AAF in Avid and look for un-rendered audio transitions and/or "add edits". It's a bit of an Avid glitch that a transition close or happening on an "add edit" will cause the AAF to fail outside the Avid. Alternately, you can have the editor output OMF's (which can require some extra work) which seem to avoid the issues entirely.

Answer (score 1):

i've seen a number of questions like this asked on the [gearslutz post production forum](http://www.gearslutz.com/board/post-production-forum/).